# Simple math operation C#

Tags: c#

I have `button`,  `Textbox` and one `label`.
I want create when user click on button number in label must be + number from textbox. and it can be unlimited time.

Example first insert 100 `label1.Text = 100`, second insert 300 
`label.text = 400`, 
third enter 700 `label.text = 1100` ...

How do this without define new variable for every click?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some of the code with error /exceptions/ undesired result

Comment: I try define new variable every time, but user can click unlimited time on button, this is simple math qouestion.

Comment: Error: Cannot convert type 'string' to 'int'

Comment: Its error, i don't know what to do ?

Comment: Try: label1.Text = (int.Parse(label1.Text) + int.Parse(textBox.Text)).ToString();

Answer (score 1):

You need not to have a new variable instead of append existing textbox value to the label

```
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(int.Parse(label1.Text) + int.Parse(textBox1.Text));
```

Happy Coding

Comment: Please take note that this will crash without an inititialization value.

Comment: Yes he has to set initial value for both of this, label and text box..I thought he get that basic implementation